# Issues when inputting a list into a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

I am currently trying to use python to insert stock data into a MySQL table (see below). Unfortunately, when I run the code it doesn't come up with any errors but appears to be taking a very long time - it wasn't complete within 10 - 15 minutes so I had to manually cancel. I am unsure if this is due to my code or if inserting data into an SQL table is an inherently slow process.

I am attempting to insert a list of tuples, which is roughly 2.3 million elements long. Given that each tuple contains 8 elements this creates a total of 18.3 million data points. The code I am using to insert this list of tuples is given below.

```
db_host = 'localhost'
db_user = 'root'
db_pass = 'password'
db_name = 'securities_master'   
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user, passwd=db_pass, db=db_name)

column_str = """price_date, symbol_id, open_price, high_price, low_price, close_price, adj_close_price, volume"""
insert_str = ("%s, " * 8)[:-2]
final_str = "INSERT INTO daily_price (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (column_str, insert_str)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany(final_str, list_of_tuples)
connection.commit()
print("Daily prices were successfully added.")
```

Where `list_of_tuples` is the aforementioned list. Furthermore, when I attempt the same process but with a smaller data set (i.e. a list of 50,000 tuples) then I encounter the same problem. I have adjusted the max allowed packets and InnoDB lock wait timeout already, as suggested in other forums.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

[image: general log]

[image: processlist when the code is running]

[image]

Comment: Look at your query log and see what queries it's generating. They should be batched with many values per `insert`, but if it's doing one `insert` per row that would be a problem. Also, is this MySQL database remote? If so, it could be a network issue. Finally, is this a running production database? Then something might be locking the table.

Comment: I didn't have general log enabled, but I've enabled it and posted a screenshot to the original post. I am unsure how to tell if it's batching many values per insert or not? To answer your other questions, the MySQL database isn't remote and I'm unsure what you mean by a running production database? This is a database I created on my personal computer that only I access.

Comment: You want the [slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html). "Production database" meaning other things are actively querying it. And if at all possible, paste the text in. Screenshots are more difficult to read and use.